# Ember-data: pushObject doesn't set parent's type and id on polymorphic association

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

here is an idiomatic hasMany/belongsTo polymorphic example where email can belongs to the many types of Contactable ('profile' is one of them) http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sibecasiga/1/edit?js,output, which is perfectly described in the http://www.toptal.com/emberjs/a-thorough-guide-to-ember-data

The problem is that after  `profile.get('emails').pushObject(email);` email's 'contactable' and 'contactableType' are empty. This is not how it is supposed to be, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the inverse in the profile model:

```
emails: DS.hasMany('email', { inverse: 'contactable' })
```

Comment: no, that won't work. there is no way to match record before and after persistence.

Comment: The type and id field were not being set until I specified the inverse relationship.

Comment: ah, yeah. that was an other issue. was too long ago ;) 
thank you for the correct answer!